# ColdFusion's cffile is adding the tmp directory to the destination attribute

Tags: coldfusion, tmp, cffile

I'm trying to upload an image to my server and the destination attribute of cffile is adding the tmp directory to the front of my destination path.

I know from another question on here that

> The destination has to be a full path, otherwise it gets sent to a directory relative to the temp directory of ColdFusion.

But I am using the full server path.  I'm in a Unix environment so its starting with /var/www/mywebsite...

This is true because it even outputs the path

```
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/\var\www\mywebsite\Gallery\
```

You can see where the tmp folders are and my intended destination.

I am also working on the right line, because when I enter different values for my intended destination, they reflect as such in the error output.

Comment: Try dumping out the result of `expandPath("/var/www/mywebsite")` and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using backslashes in your path attribute. You didn't post any code, so I am guessing, but it looks liek your cffile looks like

```
<cffile destination="\var\www\mywebsite\Gallery\" ... />
```

You should always use front slashes, especially on *nix

```
<cffile destination="/var/www/mywebsite/Gallery/" ... />
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was weird.  What going on is I'm moving these sites from an old server to a new one.  They worked perfectly fine on the old but now that they are on the new server they just broke.  Different version of coldfusion but I think it was from unix to unix.  I don't even really program in cf to top it off.  Anyway, I'm going to try "/" instead of "\" to see if that solves it.

Comment: That did the trick.  I knew this was working as is at some point, and since I don't use cf much, I figured it was supposed to be that way.  Thank you for all your help.